# Flutter calendar cancel action

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar

I want to make a variable null when user clicks on cancel button in the calendar. i gets the ok button action. but i don't know how to get cancel action

below is my code

```
Future<Null> selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
  final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: selectedDate,
    firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
    lastDate: DateTime(2101),
  );
  if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
    selectedDate = picked;
  }

  formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(selectedDate);
  print('selected date  is '+ "$formattedDate");

  setState(() {});
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

showDatePicker returns selected date to you. So if you clicked cancel button, it will return null.

If u want control cancel action, u can do this like that

```
final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: selectedDate,
  firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8),
  lastDate: DateTime(2101),
);
if(picked == null){
  print("Hi bro, i came from cancel button or via click outside of datepicker");
}
```

Comment: Also you dont need + inside print, you can use like that `print('selected date is :$formattedDate');`

Comment: And u can change `Future<Null>` to `void`, because you dont returning anything in this case.